# Initializing JFileChooser with a non-existing directory

Tags: jfilechooser

In our installation program I want to enable users to use install directory which, obviously, does not exist yet. I want that when the **Browse** button is pressed, a **JFileChooser** dialog will be opened, and will be initialized with the currently selected directory. However, **setCurrentDirectory** only works with existing directories, and **setSelectedFile** only seems to work when not working with **DIRECTORIES_ONLY** like I do.

Is there any way around this?

Thanks,

splintor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the (partial) solution I found. It is good enough for me:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(initialExistingDirectory);
FileChooserUI fileChooserUI = fc.getUI();
if (fileChooserUI instanceof BasicFileChooserUI)
{
    BasicFileChooserUI basicFileChooserUI = (BasicFileChooserUI) fileChooserUI;
    basicFileChooserUI.setFileName(initialNonExistingDirectory);
}
```